# How to append <option> from json result

Tags: javascript, select, model-view-controller, append, each

I have a Db class that called trip, which should have more then one participant, I Want to have a button that each time clicked it will generate a new select element that have an `<option>` list of all his friend.
He should be able to choose more then one friend but to the same friend twice.

I have a JsonResult function in my controller (MVC).
I have button that when clicked it will add new select with option for each friend.
I tried doing this:

```
$('#participants').append($('<div class="col-md-2"></div>'))
            .append($('<div class="input-group col-md-3"></div>')
        .append($('<span class="input-group-addon"></span>').text("Username"))
        .append($('<select name="userids" id="test" class="form-control"/>')
        .each(r, function (key, value) {
            $(this).append($('<option></option>').text(value.Text).val(value.Value))
        })
        )
        ).append($('<br>'));
```

Before that function I have those lines of code:

```
var r;
var ur = '@Url.Action("FetchFriends", "Trip")';
$.getJSON(ur, function (response) {
    if (Object.keys(response).length) {
        r = response;
    }
});
```

But it won't work.
Anyone have any idea what will work?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work" is nothing shown at all ? Do you get errors in the console? Can you confirm that `r` actually has the values you want to show in the options ?

Comment: Its just wont show the select at all....
no, I cant tell if the r is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `$.each` like that. Have a look at the doc: [jQuery.each() API Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
Let's assume your `getJSON` call actually returns the right data. And you get an array like this

```
[
  {text: 'Text 1', value: 1 },
  {text: 'Text 2', value: 2 },
  {text: 'Text 3', value: 3 }
];
```

I would strongly recommend writing some function to append your select and add the options, like so:

```
function addSelect( $element, addonText, selectName ) {
  let $wrapper = $('<div class="col-md-2"></div>');
  let $group = $('<div class="input-group col-md-3"></div>');
  let $addon = $('<span class="input-group-addon"></span>').text(addonText);
  let $select = $('<select name="'+ selectName +'" id="'+selectName+'" class="form-control"/>');
  $group.append($addon).append($select);
  $wrapper.append($group);
  $element.append($wrapper);
}
```

and

```
function addOptions($select, text, value) {
    $select.append($('<option></option>').text(text).val(value))
}
```

that way you can use these funcions in your `getJSON` Method like so:

```
$.getJSON(ur, function (response) {
    if (Object.keys(response).length) {
      $.each(response, function(key, value) {
        addSelect($('#participants), 'username', 'userids');
        let $select = $('#userids');
        addOptions($select, value.text, value.value);
      });
    }
});
```

Working example:

```js
let r = [
 {text: 'Text 1', value: 1 },
  {text: 'Text 2', value: 2 },
  {text: 'Text 3', value: 3 }
];

function addSelect( $element, addonText, selectName, options ) {
 let $wrapper = $('<div class="col-md-2"></div>');
  let $group = $('<div class="input-group col-md-3"></div>');
  let $addon = $('<span class="input-group-addon"></span>').text(addonText);
  let $select = $('<select name="'+ selectName +'" class="'+selectName+'" class="form-control"/>');
  $group.append($addon).append($select);
  $wrapper.append($group);
  $element.append($wrapper);
  $.each(options, function(key, value) {
    addOptions($select, value.text, value.value);
  });
}

function addOptions($select, text, value) {
 $select.append($('<option></option>').text(text).val(value))
}

let clicked = 1;

$('#more').on('click', function() {
  let currentId = clicked;
  clicked++;
 addSelect( $('#participants'), 'username ' + currentId, currentId, r );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="participants">

</div>
<button id="more">
more
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! But I want that the addOptions function will be called inside the addSelect function so it will acuur together.
I have an add button that calles the addSelect so only after its clicked i need the options to be set.

Comment: By calling the `addSelect` and `addOption` function inside your `getJSON` call, you only append the select when your getJSON call returned data. The given example is just a brief mockup. The point i was trying to make was that such things should always get wrapped in a function so that you can reuse it, find and read it more easily and adjust it easier if needed.

Comment: The problem is that aftyer klicking more then one time there should be more then one select with the id username

Comment: there should or should not ? I dont have the code you are talking about and as is, I would expect it to have more than one select if you click more than once.

Comment: Yes, should be more then one select. but when the .each will run if will add more options to the first select with the id instead to add more options to the new select that just created

Comment: Thats right, there would be some issues when using the same ID multiple times. Could you elaborate on your usecase ? why do you need the same select multiple times in the same form ? You could just make it `multiple` and disable the button after it was clicked, or otherwise count your clicks and change the ID of the select...

Comment: Just added more info about my desired outcome at the start of the question

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpuo9w3s/1/) for a possible solution. I will edit my answer to match the fiddle

Comment: OK, so that JS in the fiddle working good.
You have any idea how to do that when one user is choosen it will be diable or wont apear at all in the second select?

Comment: why shouldnt it ? if you want to enable users to select multiple friends without selecting one twice, use one select and make it `multiple`

Comment: I didn't understand what do you suggest... I want that each user will be able to add two friends but not the same one

Comment: If you want to select 1 or more friends but never the same one more than once, make the html element `<select>` a multiselect by adding the attribute `multiple` to it like so `<select multiple>` then you only need one select

Comment: Oho ok, Thanks! I need to install now bootstrap 4 :)